# How to add rank column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I would like to select records and determine rank number for each similar data.

My data is as follows.

```
MEMBER ID | LOAN AMOUNT 
1         | 2,000.00 
2         | 1,000.00 
3         | 4,000.00
4         | 1,000.00
```

The result I wanted is shown below.

```
RANK|MEMBER ID|LOAN AMOUNT 
1   |3        |4,000.00
2   |1        |2,000.00
3   |2        |1,000.00
3   |4        |1,000.00
```

RANK is a new column. I am using MS SQL server 2008 and created a view table as shown below but it does not resulting to what is wanted.

```
  select rank=count(*), s1.MemberID, s1.Loan_Amount 
   from (select MemberID, Loan_Amount from vwPrintTop20Borrowers) s1
   group by s1.MemberID, s1.LOAN_AMOUNT
     order by rank, s1.Loan_amount DESC
```

Please help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Which version of SQL-SERVER?

Comment: Is LOAN AMOUNT varchar?

Comment: Hi, Arulkumar, MS SQL Server 2008..

Comment: Hi, @PawełDyl . LOAN AMOUNT is decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY Loan_Amount DESC) AS Rank, 
    MemberID, LOAN_AMOUNT,
FROM vwPrintTop20Borrowers
```

Comment: Not quite: row_number produces a non-repeating, contiguous set. The OP is looking for a set with repeats.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `RANK()` :

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.loan_amount DESC) as [rank],
       t.memeber_id,t.loan_amount
FROM YourTable t
```

Although this will result in gaps E.G.

```
RANK | AMOUNT
 1        10
 2         9
 3         8
 3         8
 5         7
```

To avoid that, for SQL-Server 2008+ , use `DENSE_RANK()`

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.loan_amount DESC) as [rank]
```

Comment: Hi @sagi . Got it using DENSE_RANK(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

```
Select Dense_Rank() OVER(ORDER BY [LOAN AMOUNT] DESC) as [Rank],[MEMBER ID],[LOAN AMOUNT]  
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   select * into #P from (
   select      1  as [MEMBER ID]        , 2000.00 as  [LOAN AMOUNT]  union   all
   select     2                      , 1000.00  union all
   select     3                         , 4000.00   union all
   select     4                         , 1000.00 
 )P


 select rank()over(  order by [LOAN AMOUNT] desc) as srno,[MEMBER ID],[LOAN AMOUNT] from #P
```

Output:

```
        srno    MEMBER ID   LOAN AMOUNT
           1          3     4000.00
           2          1     2000.00
           3          2     1000.00
           3          4     1000.00
```

Comment: the over should be desc