# How do I grab a MySQL column's position?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on creating a Discord bot with a level module, and I can't seem to grab the position of a MySQL column. This is to display the current rank of the user. Here's the query:

```js
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM levels WHERE GuildID = ${message.guild.id} ORDER BY UserLvl DESC, LevelExp DESC`, function(error6, results6) {
  result_json6 = JSON.stringify(results6);
  final_result6 = JSON.parse(result_json6);
});
```

I've tried several things, from forEach to while to for and more. Is there any way to grab the position of a column and display it?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call answer your question?

Comment: Columns don't have a "position" in a SQL store. Please define what you mean by "column's position".

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - the OP clearly has a callback function coded. It is not a dupe of that question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm 90% sure he's accessing `result_json6` _outside_ the callback, but might be wrong. Hence the question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm looking to show how high the user ranks in the server regarding levels. But for that, I need to look how much EXP they have and what level they are. But I don't know where to start either. The command works but I simply can't get the ranking number to work.

Comment: @CherryPAVoice Please show us _how_ you are trying to access `result_json6`. We need to see more code to help.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv No, I didn't add a var or const value there for some dumb reason. I'm not accessing any variable displayed here from outside the callback.

Comment: Got it. Can you then show us an example of a `results6` please?

Comment: I'll log it for you, give me a minute!

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - sure that assumption makes sense here. I just figured OP was giving us some insight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add rank column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388624/how-to-add-rank-column)

Comment: I'm receiving all current data in an array format with RowDataPackets everywhere. For example:
RowDataPacket {
     id: 17,
    GuildID: 'GUILD_ID',
    UserID: 'USER_ID',
    TotalExp: 5,
    LevelExp: 5,
    ExpNeeded: 300,
    UserLvl: 0
  }

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/ or https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Comment: @CherryPAVoice - your question has to do with how to structure your database and make a specific SQL statement. Thomas' comment is probably the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define column order in the query.
For eg. `SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3... FROM TABLE`

Then retrieve column with their name and row position 0..N-1 (N = size of result6)

- If you want to get Column2 from first row, then `result6[0].Column2`
- If you want to get Column3 from second row, then `result6[1].Column3`

You can put row position using for loop, lets say i = 0 to N-1, and get the value as

```
result6[i].Column1
```